# How to pass a list as an argument to nunit console

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit-3.0

I have created a wpf application which starts nunit console for running a test suite. This wpf application taking some data which I need to send to nunit test library.
User data contains few variablea and a list of string.

Is there anyway using that we can pass data one application to another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. See below a code snippet wherein you can pass excel sheet.

```
[Test]
public void action()
{
string excelFilePath = TestContext.Parameters["excelFilePath"];
string worksheetName = TestContext.Parameters["worksheetName"];
TestContext.WriteLine(excelFilePath);
TestContext.WriteLine(worksheetName);
```

}

```
nunit3-console.exe path/to/your/test.dll --params=excelFilePath=testPath;worksheetName=testName
```